# Is requiring a dependency in requirejs really asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

if I define a module with requireJS like this.

```
define(function(require){

 var x = require("y");

  //do something with x

});
```

Why is it possible to use x instantly after requiring it? I thought `require` collects the dependencies asynchronous? I have heard that requirejs calls `toString()` on the callback function and parse it to find require statements to collect the dependencies before calling the callback. Is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you read the docs? [It's stated there](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule)!